# Displaying a ground image in rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an aerial image over an experimental area. What is the best way to show that image on the ground in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63028/displaying-a-ground-image-in-rviz?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-05-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-19**:
Can u elaborate the question..

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-19**:
Well. Suppose I have an jpg image. How do I display it in the XY plane at X=0. I know that I can build an robot model and doing a mesh that uses the image as a texture and so on. But that seems to me to complicated... Especially since I cannot get mesh files with textures to work.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-05-19**:
If it's grayscale, you could send it via an OccupancyGrid message and show it via the Map display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately I haven't seen such a DisplayType yet. Two ideas:

1. Code it yourself if you stand Qt. Personally I'd try to merge the image-subscribing code from Image-DT into the visualizing code from Map-DT.
2. If your image is nearly static, the overhead of converting it into a flat *point cloud* and transferring it might be insignificant. If your graphics can render that.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-21**:
Well, I kind of like QT but wanted to avoid having to understand the 3D code... The flat point cloud idea seems nice. I think I will test that and see how it looks.