# Customizing RViz Ground in ROS2

Tags: ros2, rviz, visualization, rviz-plugins

I am currently working on a project involving automotive radars and am using RViz in ROS2 for data visualization. My goal is to create a more realistic environment by customizing the **ground** in RViz to resemble **a road surface**.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on the following:

Changing the Ground Texture: How can I replace the default ground texture in RViz with a road-like texture? Is there a specific plugin or setting that allows for custom ground textures?

Very like in this question: [Displaying a ground image in rviz?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/51238/displaying-a-ground-image-in-rviz)

Are there any examples or tutorials available that demonstrate similar customizations in RViz?

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you code a plugin for yourself. Indeed, Rviz is just a visualization tool, not a physics simulator gui. I would consider using actual simulators like gazebo for this

Comment: @SystemSigma_ thank you very much for ur comment, yes I agree here with you. Just was thinking easy way for ground replacement, right now I am using grids with higher precision to shape needed surface, limitation is grid can have only rectangular shapes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current use of cells with a high number of grids to achieve some resemblance to the road surface. More creative and easy ways are welcome still...

[image]